# How do you set .NET Environment Variables within Self-Contained Application?

Tags: .net, azure, environment-variables, azure-appservice

Good Day,

I'm currently attempting to test deploy a .NET 5.0 Preview 8 version of my application to a Self-Contained azure app service. My current environment utilized tens of deployment profiles based on the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable that I set manually on the target app service that the application was being deployed to.

It seems that Self-Contained applications do not care nor look at the variables set directly on the app service. Which has a sense about it - self-contained being portable and all ;).

This is most likely an easy one but Google can't even answer my question or perhaps I don't know the correct question to ask. I also am not turning up much here on Stack either.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like [`this`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux#app-settings-are-injected-into-your-app-as-environment-variables-at-runtimeapplies-to-azure-app-service-on-linuxapplies-to-web-app-for-containers)?

> If you need to set an environment variable for your application,
> simply add an App Setting in the Azure portal. When your app runs, we
> will inject the app setting into the process as an environment
> variable automatically.

```
az webapp config appsettings set --name <mycontainername> --resource-group <myresourcegroupname> ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=${environment}
```